# Can plantlets on Kalanchoe be removed?

Tags: kalanchoe

I'm wondering if the plantlets on kalanchoe can be removed occasionally without affecting the plant in some anyway. To my knowledge, these structures on the leaves are basically a means of natural propagation. So if they don't serve any other function, can the plantlets occasionally be removed so that resources for the plant are directed more to plant growth rather than plantlet formation?

Answer (score 2):

That is the goal of those plantlets: With time, they detach easily and fall-off. Best time to harvest them is when they mature. As an indication, even the lightest touch will dislodge them. The way the leaves face upwards increases the chances the plantlet will land with its base facing the ground - sort of parachute - and that's where it starts to root.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. What I meant to say, though, is is it okay if I remove the plantlets? The plant is quite young and keeps shedding them off. So many of the plantlets are taking root at the base of the mother plant and I don't need that at the moment.

Comment: If you want just to take them away, that's fine.

Comment: Okay thank you.